# New entity always entered in first row in new session in a java db database table

Tags: java, database, insert, persistence

If I start up my java application a second time and try to enter a new entity row into my java db table, it inserts the new record into the first row of the table. Even though there is already records in the table. It doesn't write over the row already there, it pushes every record forward one row. Also, the primary key book id is created automatically when the new row is inserted and that side remains fine incrementing the id of the last record inserted.

I'm using a facade to create a new entity like so. Is there a way of making sure the database enters the new record in the last row at database level?

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void create(Books entity) //throws javax.persistence.EntityExistsException
{
    super.create(entity);
}
```

Comment: what is last row? it doesn't have id?

Comment: I have 5 records already in the table. I want to add another record in the row after the last record inserted. Instead, the record is been inserted in the first row with the correct id 6.